# Possible to get a lmplot in a Seaborn jointgrid using hue parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

Is there a way to get lmplot or linear regression lines in a JointGrid?

My current code is basically the exact same as the example in the Seaborn docs:

```
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species")
```

[jointplot with line and scatter plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGNXX.png)

I've also tried using `g.plot(sns.lmplot, sns.lineplot)`, as well as kdeplot. What I am going for is this below (but without the little lines on the sides). That's made using MatLab, trying to find an equivalent in Python

[joint with reg lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXEoG.png)

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the individual axes from the `JointGrid` as `g.ax_XXXX`. From there you can simply draw the regression using `regplot(..., ax=g.ax_joint)`.

```
x_col = "bill_length_mm"
y_col = "bill_depth_mm"
hue_col = "species"

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
g = sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x=x_col, y=y_col, hue=hue_col)

for _,gr in penguins.groupby(hue_col):
    sns.regplot(x=x_col, y=y_col, data=gr, scatter=False, ax=g.ax_joint, truncate=False)
```

[image]